# Strange billing byte for clustering vs specific filtered table

Tags: google-bigquery

With official docs of BQ, we can use partition with clustering to control cost of query.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#use_clustered_or_partitioned_tables

So I think we can use partition + clustering for cte reference without create temp table for simple filter. But I found  strange behavior when have same execution plan, same logic, same metric per step but different bytes cost with bellow case.

A. Query with partition and cluster, then use CTE with multi reference

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `us.ga_clustered`
PARTITION BY
  DATE_TRUNC(partition_date, MONTH)
CLUSTER BY
  event_name AS
SELECT *, PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",_TABLE_SUFFIX) as partition_date
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`;

with first_visit_home as(
    select distinct
        datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as time_click,
        date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as date_click,
        user_id,
        "first_visit_home" as event
    from `us.ga_clustered` as t
    , unnest (event_params) as t1
    where 1 = 1
        and t.event_name = "first_visit"
        and t1.key = "page_title"
        and t1.value.string_value = "Home"
        and t.partition_date between "2018-01-01" and "2022-01-01"
        and user_id is not null
)
, first_visit_gos as(
    select distinct
        datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as time_click,
        date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as date_click,
        user_id,
        "first_visit_gos" as event
    from `us.ga_clustered` as t
    , unnest (event_params) as t1
    where 1 = 1
        and t.event_name = "first_visit"
        and t1.key = 'page_title'
        and t1.value.string_value = 'Google Online Store'
        and t.partition_date between "2018-01-01" and "2022-01-01"
)

select * from first_visit_home
union all 
select * from first_visit_gos
```

and
B. Partition only with pre-filter, then use CTE with multi reference

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `us.ga_partition`
PARTITION BY
  DATE_TRUNC(partition_date, MONTH) AS
SELECT *, PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",_TABLE_SUFFIX) as partition_date
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`
  WHERE event_name = 'first_visit';

with first_visit_home as(
    select distinct
        datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as time_click,
        date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as date_click,
        user_id,
        "first_visit_home" as event
    from `us.ga_partition` as t
    , unnest (event_params) as t1
    where 1 = 1
        and t.event_name = "first_visit"
        and t1.key = "page_title"
        and t1.value.string_value = "Home"
        and t.partition_date between "2018-01-01" and "2022-01-01"
        and user_id is not null
)
, first_visit_gos as(
    select distinct
        datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as time_click,
        date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), 'Asia/Bangkok') as date_click,
        user_id,
        "first_visit_gos" as event
    from `us.ga_partition` as t
    , unnest (event_params) as t1
    where 1 = 1
        and t.event_name = "first_visit"
        and t1.key = 'page_title'
        and t1.value.string_value = 'Google Online Store'
        and t.partition_date between "2018-01-01" and "2022-01-01"
)

select * from first_visit_home
union all 
select * from first_visit_gos
```

Both A and B return same result set, with same execution graph and metrics as bellow
[image]

But byte cost is different: 54.88 MB(B) and 109.76 MB(A)

Can someone explain this? and which usecase prefer use clustering(A) than prefilter as table(B)
I think this case is very confusing then how can detect that as anti pattern in BQ?

Thanks everyone.

Confusing case when bigquery calculate cost with cte multi reference

Comment: It's expected since you have decreased the size of the table in B, by filtering by event_name. Clustering is not partitioning, it doesn't guarantee to keep an event_name isolated in the storage. So, at the end, you end up scanning more data in example B.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you to partition by date instead of month since it's more granular.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen 
1.I partition by month cause example table of public google dataset so small then maybe it can affect to final byte cost calculated.
2. If behavior of cluster and prefilter table is different, then will be in case using cte with multi reference can have byte cost more than table size(will not occur and not consistent if query with same table without cluster can have byte cost never more than table size). I don't think that be normal behavior in general. And if that true, maybe we shoud add to best practice/pitfall when use cluster table.

Comment: To more clear, `create table tb_a cluster by 
  col_1 AS select * from tb_source` and `create table tb_b as select * from tb_source`, if we define cte query from tb_a with multi reference, then maybe final cost can larger than tb_a size, but if we query cte from tb_b, final cost never larger than tb_b size.